# Is it possible to insert a computed attribute (i.e. non-constant) into an XML file with xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file like this:

**sources.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sources>
  <source>
    <identity id="abc"/>
    <somestuff/>
  </source>
  <source>
    <identity id="def"/>
    <someotherstuff/>
  </source>
</sources>
```

I want to get rid of the tag `identity` and transfer its attribute into the parent node. With other words, I need to change my input file into:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sources>
  <source id="abc">
    <somestuff/>
  </source>
  <source id="def">
    <someotherstuff/>
  </source>
</sources>
```

I tried:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  --insert "//source" --type attr --name "id" --value "identity/@id" \
  --delete "//identity" \
  sources.xml
```

which is not working because `--value` understands its argument as a constant string.

My question is: is it possible for *xmlstarlet* to compute the value of the attribute `id` as an XPATH expression like in the `select` operations?

**Edit nr. 1**

I found a way to get something done in that direction:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  --insert "//source" --type attr --name "id" --value "{PLACE HOLDER}" \
  --update "//source/@id" --expr "../identity/@id" \
  --delete "//identity" \
  sources.xml
```

but I get empty values for attribute `id`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sources>
  <source id="">
    <somestuff>Hello</somestuff>
  </source>
  <source id="">
    <someotherstuff/>
  </source>
</sources>
```

What is wrong in the expression `../identity/@id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and this is the solution:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  --insert "//source" --type attr --name "id" \
  --update "//source/@id" --expr "string(../identity/@id)" \
  --delete "//identity" \
  sources.xml
```

The `--insert` operation doesn't admit `--expr` parameters, only `--value`, but `--update` does. So we do it in two different steps: first create an empty attribute and second, change its value with `--expr`.

We also need to convert the text node given as argument to the option `--expr` into a string with the XPATH function `string()`. This is unsufficiently documented in the references or tutorials.

Comment: That's a great idea! I've been struggling with similar problems for a while and was about to post a similar question! Side note: in your search for this solution, did you run into a situation where you had to grab the `--value` or `--expr` from a system variable instead of from inside the same xml?

Comment: @JackFleeting: I just found the solution 12 minutes ago on the XML file you see above. So I didn't try other things.

Comment: I think I figured it out; if it's ok with you, I can post it as an additional answer, for future readers.

Comment: @JackFleeting: OK.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, but one where the computed attribute had to be taken from a system variable. So, with OPs permission, I figured I'd post it here as well, for future reference.

if

```
myvar="hello"
```

this would insert "hello" as the `id` attribute value:

```
xmlstarlet edit   --insert "//source" --type attr --name "id"\
   --update "//source/@id" --value "$myvar"   --delete "//identity"   sources.xml
```

Note: this time we have to use `--value`, not `--expr`.